# Unable to change the value of a variable in python, if-statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I have a very simple script, the goal is that if someone enters a number between 40 and 49 for raw_input, the value of `ageRisk` should change from 0 to 0.004

```
age = raw_input("Enter your age: ")

ageRisk = 0

if age >= 40 and age < 50:
    ageRisk = 0.004

print ageRisk
```

However when I run this script entering 44 for the `raw_input`, the value for `ageRisk` remains at 0. Why is this?

Comment: You should switch from Python 2.7 to Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the user's input is a *string*. To fix this, change your line `age = raw_input("Enter your age: ")` into `age = int(raw_input("Enter your age: "))`

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this:

`age = raw_input("Enter your age: ")`

to:

`age = int(raw_input("Enter your age: "))`

The default for input is to treat everything as a string, and if not converted your logical does not see the numerical value it needs to reassign the values.

Answer (score 2):

Your raw_input is taking in a number as a string. to resolve this, convert the input into an integer.

```
age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, `raw_input()` returns a `string`, not an integer.

You need to wrap your `raw_input()` in an `int()` call to convert it.

`int(raw_input())` takes user input and returns an integer (if one was entered).